# How to migrate My Server OS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, migration, centos7

I've been researching the past week or so on how to migrate my Windows 2008R2 Server to Linux CentOS, I thought I had a good grip on it but know I'm confused and my networking knowledge isn't as up to par as I thought.

Windows Server 2008R2 is currently running.
DHCP
DNS
Active Directory

I have a Spare server with Centos 7 Currently installed "Server With GUI" when installing.

So, I'm wondering, where do I start?
What's the best practice for changing OS?

From what i have found online there isn't a step by step manual, eg, You start with DHCP, then DNS, then etc. etc. etc..

Or if there is I Haven't Found it.

My End goal is to have the Linux Server running everything, but I do not want to interrupt the current Windows Server until I'm essentially plugging it out.

My thought process/goal was.

1. Setup DNS
2. Connect Computer To Domain And Test
3. Setup Temoprary File Server
4. Connect Computer To Test
5. Build PXE Boot Server For Installing Operating System
6. Test PXE Server Over Network On One Machine
7. Setup DHCP
8. Test Machines On New DHCP Server
9. Test Software With Server/File Server
10. Install Linux on all Machines
11. Take Lunch

But I couldn't get the DNS working properly, I followed this guide
https://www.unixmen.com/setting-dns-server-centos-7/

So now i'm questioning if I missed a step, what needs to be done in order for this to work.

Does anyone have anyone know how I can approach this in the most efficient way?
are there any good books I can follow or tutorials on how to approach something like this?

All I need is a list of steps and then I can figure it out from there.

Comment: I don't know about books, but your approach is very good. Only swap 2 first points. First connect to domain then set up DNS on it. And pass DNS management to bind - and create clustered bind - just for sake of resiliency. Domain, BIND (if possible second server with bind), SAMBA (a lot of things can be done with it especially for deduplication) and rest of your things.

Answer (score 1):

Hire someone who knows what s/he is doing.

Sorry if this seems rude, but you are trying to perform ***a full Windows-to-Linux migration of your entire environment*** (which would be *quite* a challenging task even for a seasoned professional) without having the slightest bit of a clue about what, when and how needs to be done.